# Backward diodes VI curve

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, analog

I am searching for the IV curve of a backward diode but couldn't find anything, any help?

Comment: What type of diode and how many datasheets did you search?

Comment: A backward diode:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_diode

Comment: Here’s a Sch Diode in simulation -51 to 1V. https://tinyurl.com/ygrbwm26

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but a quick Google search gave me these results on the first page: [[1](https://www.americanmicrosemi.com/tutorial/tunnel-diode-and-back-diode/)], [[2](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/Back_diode)]. They seem to provide I-V characteristic curves; if this is insufficient can you edit your question to better clarify the question you actually have?

Comment: Is anybody making commercially available backward diodes anymore?  The last ones I know of were in germanium which is all but dead.

Answer (score 6):

If you just need an IV-curve of a random backward diode, the [German Wikipedia site](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward-Diode) has one:

[image]

(Unknown authorUnknown author, Public domain, via Wikimedia Commons)

There is a hint, that the diagram might be flipped by 180 ° compared to those of a tunnel diodes. So the right side of that picture is actually the reverse polarity side. Not sure why it was done like that.

Comment: What do you mean by any IV curve?

Comment: Of just "a back diode" without any specific model or use case in mind.

Comment: by moving to the right in your picture we go to the reverse voltages correct?

Comment: https://www.americanmicrosemi.com/tutorial/tunnel-diode-and-back-diode/

Comment: @MissMulan yes, there is actually a note which mentions, that it is flipped by 180° compared to normal tunnel diodes, no idea why they did it. I've added that not to my answer.

Comment: Are you German?

Comment: @MissMulan If you just over over the name of Arsenal you'll find enough information to have strong evidence that the answer is "yes." As a side note, you could also just ask, "Sind Sie Deutcher?" (To others, not necessarily you who may already know all this, that question doesn't imply male or female. Oddly, "jeder Deutsche" is also generic and doesn't imply either, through "jede Deutsche" would imply "jede Deutsche Frau". Weak declensions in German make things complex to English speakers, I think.)

Comment: @jonk i don't know how to speak German.Are you too German?

Comment: @MissMulan yes, I'm indeed German.

Comment: @MissMulan No. I just read German fairly well and, on occasion, can manage to speak a little of it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of your terminology globally. My apologies.
[18GHz Planar Tunnel (Back) diode datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/017/ASTD-2030-820-pdf.php)

A **Backward Diode(EU) or Back Diode (USA) is a special type with much higher negative  impedance and low capacitance** which can be biased to be an amplifier, rectifier or switch for UHF to EHF microwave (EHF means >30 GHz, UHF is <30 GHz) It uses an expensive process for a crystal semiconductor fabricated with such low impurities that it has a breakdown voltage ratio of 50kV/mm. (Although similar low impurity levels are required for the smallest lithography CMOS).

As such it is a very specialized process with a very narrow gap in Germanium and not your “garden variety” commercial diode so it is only produced by specialized high purity foundries with specialized expensive annealing and high doping chemical processes.

This led to the recent development of other shallow negative resistance devices using Indium Gallium Arsenide Nitride over Gallium Arsenide InGaAsN/GaAs for high efficiency (43%) solar panels.

Others may find companies who make these types  but one of the first “Back Diodes” were the 1N371x series found in old data books.

Dr. Leo [Esaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Esaki) (Sony) was credited with a Nobel Prize in Physics for explaining the Quantum Tunnelling effect in 1958 so IMHO his name ought to be used for Tunnel diodes. *”back diode” was used by Horowitz’s books for this “Back” diode  special version of Tunnel Diodes which has lower capacitance and higher resistance than the classic Tunnel diodes.*

You would have to lookup old GE transistor books to find the ones Esaki used on [archive.org. 1N3716](https://archive.org/details/semiconductordat00gene/mode/2up?q=1N3716)

### Detector

It has low capacitance and much higher “negative incremental resistance” or smaller hump when reverse biased, almost like a normal diode leakage which has only a positive incremental resistance that is rises sharply near the Vr limit .

This  class of diode has such a low capacitance that it has  no charge storage effect.

The hump which rises slower with neg. R than a Tunnel diode strongly nonlinear because of this change in polarity if resistance for small signals.

As an FM/AM detector it can be used as a detector up to 40 GHz. Esaki designed the Tunnel diode (Germanium Arsenic ) into the SONY FM Radio (EFM-117) radio and it still works today.

### Rectifier

A backward diode can be used for rectifying weak signals with peak amplitudes of 0.1 to 0.7 V.

### Switch

A backward diode can be used in high speed switching applications.

But it shares the leakage sensitivity of a normal diode.

Reverse leakage is very temperature sensitive and constant till Vr max , so often just the table values  are given at 25’C and 125’C which is orders of magnitude worse.

Here’s one sample see Fig 3

https://www.taiwansemi.com/assets/uploads/datasheet/TSUP5M45SH_A1909.pdf

```
Esaki’s Do’s and Don’ts 
-

Don't allow yourself to be trapped by your past experiences.
Don't allow yourself to become overly attached to any one authority in your field – the great professor, perhaps.
Don't hold on to what you don't need.
Don't avoid confrontation.
Don't forget your spirit of childhood curiosity.
```

Comment: This datasheet is not for a backward diode. A backward diode isnt a diode in reverse bias. A backward diode is its own type of diode.

Comment: @Matt a backward bias current plot is what was in the question. I think you mean a “Back Diode” which we know is different. Use the proper terms forward, backward current vs a “back diode” don’t confuse our students please. You have confused 5 already. “Backward diode “  is used in the UK and I guess in EU while a Back Diode is the term used in North America, while in Japan they are called “Esaki Diodes”

Comment: "backward bias current plot" is nowhere to be found in the question and I dont see that the question was edited. Both names "backward diode" and "back diode" are in common use to describe the same thing. I cant speak to all the regions you listed but I'm more familiar with the former name in the US. But either way this is an international site. "Esaki diode" is another name for a "tunnel diode" and is similar, but not exactly the same thing. Both names are commonly us use in the US.

Comment: Leo Esaki himself discusses backward diodes and tunnel diodes as separate things. The tunnel diode is the one that shares his name: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1478480

Comment: Right but back to the question I guess I have only seen datasheets. From GE for (Back) used by Esaki and not backward , although the common diode terms are forward and reverse. Just semantics...